# Source IP from UDP packet in c under window OS

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, windows

I want to get the source IP of UDP packet kindly guide me so that I can make it possible. I am working in c under windows platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [recvfrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120(VS.85).aspx) function. It has a `from` parameter that points to a sockaddr structure that will receive the source address.

Comment: Actually my application is in sniffer mode, so that I can't use the recvfrom function.

Comment: What does that mean - what API are you using for sniffing ?

Comment: @Arman, wait, so what's the matter with the recvfrom in your case? I believe that the link in the post you marked as an answer also suggests using the function

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.sockets.com/ch16.htm

There you should find some code that can guide you in the right direction!

This should help you:

sockaddr structure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740496(VS.85).aspx

in_addr structure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738571(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[recvfrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916174.aspx) is what you need